# Trigger JavaScript-loader while waiting for data

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, loading

I am trying to add a loader to my website which should be visible while the page is "loading".

Eg. the load time is ca. 6,8 seconds (6,3 seconds waiting and 0,4 seconds downloading). I want my loader to be visible for the whole 6,8 seconds but as it is now, it just shows at the last some seconds.

Heres my code:
HTML:

```
<div id="tpa-preloader"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#mk-boxed-layout{ display: none; }

#tpa-preloader{
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background:url(/preloader.gif) no-repeat #FFFFFF 50%;
    -moz-background-size:148px 128px;
    -o-background-size:148px 128px;
    -webkit-background-size:148px 128px;
    background-size:148px 128px;
    z-index: 99998;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function onReady(callback) {
    var intervalID = window.setInterval(checkReady, 1000);

    function checkReady() {
        if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] !== undefined) {
            window.clearInterval(intervalID);
            callback.call(this);
        }
    }
}

function show(id, value) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = value ? 'block' : 'none';
}

onReady(function () {
    show('mk-boxed-layout', true);
    show('tpa-preloader', false);
});
```

Here's the link to my website: http://nettbutikk-sandbox.ellco.me/produkt/o35/

How can I make `tpa-preloader` visible for the whole 6,8 seconds, meaning from the very start of a loading process?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Like most languages JS also use sequence access. I wanna say :

1. Put your loader code on top html page.
   To load library. Then :

   < body >

   ```
    <script>

     // Init you preloader

     // After this script put all other.... 

     // then use window.onload and put on bottom some 
     // setTimeout ( 4-6 sec ) then timer will trigger func hide preloader...
   </script>
   ```

Comment: You should add more code to your example. This is not really a good answer to OP's question, even though it is a good idea. :)

Comment: No, you have no code implemented that works. You outline a possible solution, but that is not the same. Update your example with actual code, such as the `setTimeout` you're talking about, or the hiding of the `preloader`. :)

Comment: I have to agree with @ThomasDarvik. As a beginner in JavaScript, I have difficulties understanding your suggestion. Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: When i found time i will improve answer !